# How to update server-side changes on the client side for Blazor Server app?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

My **ChangeValues** server-side event occurs every 5 seconds but on client-side, I only see the first value of the **number** variable.
See code below

```cs
@page "/"
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ChangeValues">Click me</button>
<b>@number</b>
@code {
    double number;
    private Random rnd = new Random();
    private System.Threading.Timer _timer;
    void ChangeValues()
    {
        number = rnd.NextDouble();
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
    private void DoWork(object state)
    {
        ChangeValues();
    }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, 
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a Timer (that will fire on another Thread) you have to call StateHasChanged() using Invoke:

```
private async void DoWork(object state)
{
    ChangeValues();
    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);        
}
```